# Bioconductor package installation : missing repository

Tags: r, shiny, bioconductor, r-graphviz

I am trying to publish a shiny app, but getting the following error. My code is working fine in Rstudio though. Only get this error when I try to publish it.

```
       install.packages("BiocManager")

 
     BiocManager::install("Rgraphviz")
```

> Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 1195199124 failed: Error parsing manifest: Unable to determine package source for Bioconductor package BiocGenerics: Repository must be specified
> Execution halted

How can I solve this problem? How to specify a repository? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before publishing your app, run `options(repos = BiocManager::repositories())` on your console. Do NOT copy this code to your app scripts. Then, publish your app. No need of `install.packages("BiocManager")` or `BiocManager::install("Rgraphviz")`